# Is this an accurate and exhausive list of the scope defining mechanisms in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is this an accurate and exhausive list of variable visibility (ie. scope) -defining mechanisms in JavaScript (assume ES2015+)?

1. function body (all types of function including generators and class-related syntax that corresponds to functions, getters, setters)
2. function signature (if you consider parameters variables)
3. catch block
4. block (for `let` and `const`, plus hoisting consideration)
5. for-loop header declaration (for `let`)
6. closure
7. module
8. global object (realm?)
9. `eval` and `new Function(<string>)`(?) (in strict mode)
10. arguably object references (ie. pass by value of the reference)(?)
11. function definition kinds (declaration, statement, expressed)

Comment: Maybe anything with brackets + modules + globals?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Scope_Cheatsheet